# Recording an RGB video with the Kinect

Tags: c#, video, kinect, directshow, kinect-sdk

I am using the Microsoft Kinect SDK in my project (latest version - 1.7), with C# WPF.

and I am trying to record a video (rgb+audio, no IR or depth) using my Kinect sensor,

While windows recognizes the Kinect as valid microphone, it does not recognize it as a standard webcam.

How do I solve this issue ?

P.S.

I tried saving the RGB images one-by-one and merging them into a video, but this method causes low frame-rate and syncing issues (with the sound stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're can use [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) drivers.